# $\frac{|| \overline{AM}||}{|| \overline{AB}||}=\frac{|| \overline{AN}||}{|| \overline{AC}||}=\frac{|| \overline{MN}||}{|| \overline{BC}||}$

Tags: geometry, proof-writing, analytic-geometry

> $\Delta ABC$ is a triangle, $M$ is a point in the segment $\overrightarrow{AB}$ and $N$ is a point in the segment $\overrightarrow{AC}$, such that $\overrightarrow{MN}$ is parallel to $\overrightarrow{BC}$. Show that
>
> $$\frac{|| \overrightarrow{AM}||}{|| \overrightarrow{AB}||}=\frac{|| \overrightarrow{AN}||}{|| \overrightarrow{AC}||}=\frac{|| \overrightarrow{MN}||}{|| \overrightarrow{BC}||}$$
>
> **Hint:** Consider $r,s,t\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\overrightarrow{AN}=r\cdot \overrightarrow{AC}$, $\overrightarrow{MN}=s\cdot \overrightarrow{BC}$ and $\overrightarrow{AM}=t\cdot \overrightarrow{AB}$ and use the fact that $\overrightarrow{AB}$ and $\overrightarrow{BC}$ are linearly independent to prove $r=s=t$.

I've had this question on my exam and I thought that I needed to assume first that:

$$\frac{|| \overrightarrow{AM}||}{|| \overrightarrow{AB}||}=\frac{|| \overrightarrow{AN}||}{|| \overrightarrow{AC}||}=\frac{|| \overrightarrow{MN}||}{|| \overrightarrow{BC}||}$$

Because otherwise, I'd be assuming arbitrary triangles that wouldn't work in this case (I guess). But the professor said that this is what I should prove, with his comment I assumed that this should be the conclusion in the proof - the last step perhaps. But from here, I have no idea on how to proceed, I've meditated about the premise on the linear independence, but I'm out of ideas. I don't know the order in which I should assume what is given in the question in order to prove it.

Comment: This is a basic rule about similar triangles (which you know because $\overline {MN} || \overline{BC}$. I'm assuming from the question that your task is to prove the rule without using that basic rule? Also, the assumption you wrote is exactly the same as the "Show that" statement. Did you mean to write something else?

Comment: @Duncan Show that $\frac{|| \overrightarrow{AM}||}{|| \overrightarrow{AB}||}=\frac{|| \overrightarrow{AN}||}{|| \overrightarrow{AC}||}=\frac{|| \overrightarrow{MN}||}{|| \overrightarrow{BC}||}$.

Answer (score 2):

Edit:(correct mistake)

$\overrightarrow{AM}+\overrightarrow{MN}+\overrightarrow{NA}=0 \\ \implies t\overrightarrow{AB}+s\overrightarrow{BC}+r\overrightarrow{CA}=0 \\ \implies t\overrightarrow{AB}+s\overrightarrow{BC}+r(-(\overrightarrow{AB}+\overrightarrow{BC}))=0 \\ \implies (t-r)\overrightarrow{AB}+(s-r)\overrightarrow{BC}=0$

$\overrightarrow{AB}$ , $\overrightarrow{BC}$ is linear independent $\implies t-r=0,s-r=0$

Comment: I didn't get why you assumed that $\overrightarrow{AM}+\overrightarrow{AN}+\overrightarrow{MN}=0$.

Comment: it is a triangle.it is similar to $\overrightarrow{AB}+\overrightarrow{AC}+\overrightarrow{BC}=0$

Comment: Can you expand a little more on how did you get these steps? I'm a little lost.

Comment: here is a mistake for AC and correct it.

Comment: $\overrightarrow{AB}+\overrightarrow{BC}=\overrightarrow{AC}$ is definition of vector adding.

Comment: @IgäriaMnagarka - the first statement is not an assumption, it's a fact. If three vectors make a triangle, then when you "add" them together, you end up back at the same point (that's how a triangle works). It's slightly more correct to say that they sum to the 0 vector, not to 0, but the end result is the same.